# Как добавить поддержку соотношения сторон 18:9 в Ionic Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic, кроссплатформенность

Никак не могу добавить поддержку нового формата соотношения сторон 18:9 в своё android приложение на ionic framework. Использую 6" смартфон Xiaomi Redmi S2. Приложение запускается, но внизу  висит черная полоса придающая приложению стандартное соотношение сторон 16:9. Прошу объяснить максимально простым языком, что надо сделать, что бы приложение работало в полную высоту.

[image: Xiaomi Redmi S2 с приложением не поддерживающее новый формат соотношения сторон]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Надо в файле My10 copy\platforms\android\CordovaLib\AndroidManifest.xml дописать следующее между тегами manifest

```
<application>
        <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
 </application>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]